# How to create a SNS Filter Policy that matches nested message attributes?

Tags: amazon-sns

I've created an SNS topic, and I'd like to subscribe to it with a [filter policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/message-filtering.html) that matches a nested attribute. For example, given a message like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "baz"
  },
  "quux": "vorp"
}
```

I'd like to match only messages where the `bar` attribute of `foo` is equal to `baz`.

The documentation I've found so far only mentions matching attributes specified at the top level. I'm interested in a nested attribute. For the purposes of this question, let's assume I don't control the structure of the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of 2022, it's possible to filter based on the payload.

That's mentioned here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-filtering.html

An Example of filtering:

Let's say your original message is like:

```
{
  "eventType": "SOME_STRING",
  "otherAttribs": "bla..."
}
```

Then the filter can be something like:

```
{
  "eventType": [
    {
      "prefix": "SAMETH"
    }
  ]
}
```

In AWS WebConsole, it's found in SNS -> Subscriptions -> [select one] -> Subscription filter policy.

Answer (score 25):

Subscription filters don't act on the message (body, payload).  They only act on the [*message attributes*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SNSMessageAttributes.html).

Message attributes are not complex objects... their only types are string, string array, number, and binary.  If a message attribute contains a serialized object (e.g. JSON), subscription filters aren't designed to support extracting/matching the serialized data inside.

Comment: Message body (payload) filters have recently been introduced

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/

Comment: Thanks, this was the accepted answer for a long time! I withdrew acceptance only because the facts changed (AWS introduced a new feature), making this answer is no longer true.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a subscription filter with the "Message body" filter type.

For your example, to match only messages where the `bar` attribute of `foo` is equal to `baz` in this message:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": "baz"
  },
  "quux": "vorp"
}
```

Your filter would look like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": ["baz"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now, SNS can filter events based on their payload as well. With this release, the SNS filter policy can handle property nesting too. For more information, please take a look at: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-payload-based-message-filtering-for-amazon-sns/